# How can I develop a Cortana app in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, cortana

I would like to develop a Cortana application in HTML/JavaScript/CSS. Unfortunately, all the [documentation pertaining to Cortana apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/cortana-interactions) is written for C#/XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate with Cortana, you need to develop a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app which exposes an "App Service" that integrates with Cortana.

In Visual Studio 2015 (or Visual Studio 15), create a new project using the JavaScript project template "Blank App (Universal Windows)". Find the element with tag `Application`, and add the following as a child element:

```
<Extensions>
  <!-- Provide a hook for Cortana to ask your app questions -->
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" StartPage="voiceCommandService.js"> 
    <uap:AppService Name="AdventureWorksVoiceCommandService"/> 
  </uap:Extension>
  <!-- Enable deep linking into your app from Cortana -->
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.personalAssistantLaunch"/>
</Extensions>
```

The file `voiceCommandService.js` will then serve as an entry point for Cortana. It will be executed whenever Cortana hands off a request to your app, and you'll be able to get the task details from `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIBackgroundTaskInstance.current`.

For the rest, just follow the C# documentation.

Answer based on [this Cortana sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand/js).